# EmberJS - Click() helper doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-testing, acceptance

When passing the JQuery selector to the click() method in emberjs, while testing, the element doesn't get clicked.
I'm trying to write a simple acceptance test where an element  with an id and an href gets clicked and the URL changes, and then I assert that the page changed.

I added the id to the `<a>` element id="sidebar-user-profile" and when I try `click($('#sidebar-user-profile'))` I get the error "Error: Element [object Object] not found.". I tried doing the same, while on the page, in Chrome's console by typing `$('#sidebar-user-profile')` and it selected that exact element.

I've been trying to get this to work for the past 2 weeks and I'm out of options.

edit: Here's the test that has the error:

```js
test('exists and works /home/user-profile', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);
  click('#sidebar-user-profile');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/home/user-profile');
  });
});
```

```html
<li>{{#link-to 'home.user-profile' id="sidebar-user-profile"}}User Profile{{/link-to}}</li>
```

Comment: `click('#sidebar-user-profile');`

Comment: Remember to have the assert wrapped in an `andThen`

Comment: Ok, now the error isn't "Error: Element [object Object] not found.", now it's "Error: Element #sidebar-user-profile not found."

Comment: Can you add the template code? Also are you on the correct route when the test is running? add a `return pauseTest();` before the click and check that you're in the right place

Comment: You might need to add a `visit('/home')` at the start of the test if that's where the link is.

Comment: Hmm. I seems that I actually might not be at the right place. Nice catch. Even after I added visit('/home'); I still wasn't at the right place. Looks like the login page takes a bit to go through before it actually lands on the /home page. I need to find a way to skip login.

Comment: You will need a login helper, or you ll need yo re-open the login route and have it return true

Comment: Thank you very much. I was banging my head on the wall trying to figure this out.

Comment: No problem, If you get stuck on the login helper ping me here ^^

Comment: @Kitler, The login helper only needs to "manually" log me in, before every test, right? My login consists only of two separate clicks on two separate pages. Start page has a "Login" button and the next page has "Login with Google" button which opens a popup which logs you in with your current google account. How do I go about writing the helper so that he waits for the popup to disappear after you click on the button? Because right now i get the error "Error: Popup could not open or was closed".

Comment: You should stub the signing in with google part and the helper should be an async helper.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to stub. The helper is async. I used ember generate to generate it. Is there any resource online that you can point me towards that would help me with stubbing this?

Comment: The ember room on IRC would be a more suitable place for this.

Answer (score 1):

Click takes a selector not a jquery object, your test would look something like:

```
click('#sidebar-user-profile');
andThen(() => {
  assert.equal(currentURL(), `/myurl/new`, 'Should go to new route');
});
```

Edit:

```
test('exists and works /home/user-profile', function(assert) {
  visit('/home'); // route where your link-to is located
  click('#sidebar-user-profile');
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/home/user-profile');
  });
});
```